# Update table from another table using stored procedure

Tags: sql-server-2008

I am working in SQL Server 2008 R2.  I have a table that is going to be my main activity table for a SSRS report.  I need to update the table with information in another table that is created by a recurring job which queries my ERP database and collects specific records.  I need to update the main table with five fields from this other table without disturbing the existing data.

Main table has 14 fields, table from ERP has 6. The ones in common are :
Job#
JobName
Reference
Pages
Due Date
Customer

If the job# exists in the main table I would like to move to the next record.  I was going to do a stored procedure that would go through the records oneat a time.  I have done this in Excel but not in SQL.  Also from a best practices perspective, would I be better off putting the query of the ERP database and this update in a single stored procedure or create a new one and create a job that runs them in succession?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

SQL is set based, so you should do your best to avoid any row by row logic.  Without your schema I'm only guessing but....

```
UPDATE main
set Field1 = other.Field1,
    Field2 = other.Field2,
    Field3 = other.Field3
from MainTable main
INNER JOIN ERP other
ON main.[Job#] = other.[Job#]
and main.JobName = other.JobName
and main.Reference = other.Reference
and main.Pages = other.Pages
and main.[Due Date] = other.[Due Date]
and main.Customer = other.Customer
```

Comment: I think he's saying he wants to skip matching job numbers. If so, lose the first JOIN statement and at the end add "WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM main WHERE [JOB#] = other.[JOB#])" to the very end.

Comment: Here is what I ended up using:                                                             merge DashMaster a
 using DashActiveJobs b
 on a.Activity = b.Ref
 when not matched by target then
 insert(Activity,JobName,JobNumber,Pages)
 values(b.Ref,b.JobName,b.JobNumber,b.Pages);